# VueJS Ecountering nextTick : " Error: Invalid argument" in IE

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer

Any one who have experience an error when you are using IE. Can you help with this scenario for possible alternative or fix.

[image: Console error message]

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10285. Go ahead and add the reproducible example there.

Comment: Only error message will not give much idea about the cause for the issue. I suggest you to post any sample code which can produce the issue. We will try to test that sample code with IE browser to find the cause and possible solution or work around.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem this way, here an example:

Change your interpolation from this

```
    <div class="message">
        <p>{{ error_message }}</p>
    </div>
```

to this:

```
    <div class="message">
        <p v-text="error_message"></p>
    </div>
```